# 2d array in c# index search with array using lambda expression

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2d array:-

```
int[,] group = {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10},{11,12,13,14,15},{16,17,18,19,20},{21,22,23,24,25},};
```

now, aside from that I have two other arrays:-

`int[]array1= new int[]{0,2,4};`

`int[]array2= new int[]{1,3};`

what I want is a resultant array which take its width from array1 and length from array2
, so that the resultant array

arrayrel={group[0,1],group[0,3],group[2,1],group[2,3],group[4,1]group[4,3] }

`arrayrel={2,4,12,14,22,24}`

this can be done using loop I was wondering if there is a method to achieve this result using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select` and then `SelectMany`:

```
int[] arrayrel = array1.Select(i => array2.Select(j => group[i, j])).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

The first `Select` yields an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, which you flatten using `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it as follows:

```
var result = array1.SelectMany(row => array2.Select(col => group[row, col]));
```

If you want to convert the result from `IEnumerable<int>` to `int[]` you need to add `toArray()` at the end of the statement.